# Can $\int_{1/2}^x \cot(\pi x)dx$ converge, where $x>1$.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Consider the definite integral $$\int_{1/2}^x\cot(\pi x)~dx,$$ where $x>1$. As $x\rightarrow 1$ from below $\cot(\pi x)\rightarrow-\infty$, but as $x\rightarrow 1$ from above $\cot(\pi x)\rightarrow+\infty$. My question is this:

Could the definite integral in fact converge for $x>1$ so long as the rate at which the infinities either side of $x=1$ are reached are the same?

---

Furthermore, is it possible for $$\int_0^x\cot(\pi x)~dx$$ to converge, where $0<x<1$, even though $\lim\limits_{x\to0}= +\infty$ ?

Comment: That is then known as a principal value integral. $$v.p. \int_{1/2}^x \cot (\pi t)\,dt := \lim_{\varepsilon \searrow 0} \left(\int_{1/2}^{1-\varepsilon} \cot (\pi t)\,dt + \int_{1+\varepsilon}^x \cot (\pi t)\,dt\right)$$

Comment: I think my "furthermore" must depend on the Laurent expansion of the integrand. In this case, I don't think the "furthermore" part would converge since the Laurent series of the integrand contains a $c\cdot 1/x$ term? Then again this depends on whether we can interchange integral and sum...

Comment: The integrand has a pole of order $1$ in $0$, with residue $1/\pi$. That is a non-integrable singularity, $$\lim_{\varepsilon\searrow 0} \int_{\varepsilon}^x \cot (\pi t)\,dt = +\infty$$ for every $x \in (0,1)$. You have the (boring) principal value $$\lim_{\varepsilon\searrow 0} \int_{\varepsilon}^{1-\varepsilon} \cot (\pi t)\,dt = 0.$$

Comment: You shouldn't use $x$ both for the limit of integration and the variable of integration.